# Enable Snap Feature to Winform for Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

I am building an application in VS2012 using winforms and want to enable it for the "snap" feature introduced in Windows 7. When I try to "snap" my current window nothing happens. Is there anything I need to modify on my form to enable this feature?

Comment: The form should be treated like any other Windows window, and you should be able to "snap" it. There is nowhere to disable it as far as I'm aware. Are you using the default Winform style, or have you added a theme to the form?

Comment: I am using the default Winform style. I am a bit mystified as to why it won't snap.

Comment: Snap won't work if your window implements its own resizing/moving/docking behaviour. Does it do that?

Comment: That solved it, I had the `FormBorderStyle` set to fixed. Thanks!